# Is there a standard or recommended format for encrypted data, with algorithmic agility?

Tags: standards, file-format, crypto-agility

I am storing relatively small (from a few bytes to less than 50MB) amounts of encrypted data for an extended period. This data is encrypted using a custom tool that has already been in use for some time. I am reviewing the current implementation and am considering whether I need to make any changes. I must retain support for previously encrypted files and so (I think) must keep the leading Format ID to distinguish between formats. Beyond that, I am free to modify the configuration as I like.

If there is a standard or de facto format that would provide algorithmic agility, I would much prefer that to roll my own. Is there such a thing?

Alternatively, what standards/best practices apply to developing such a format? Are there any particular pitfalls I should bear in mind?

The existing format currently is as follows:

```
## File format                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                  
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |           Format ID            |  1 byte                                                                      
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |        Unused (Legacy)         |  3 bytes                                                                     
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |           Cipher ID            |  2 bytes                                                        
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |            HMAC ID             |  2 bytes
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |      Initialization Vector     |  16 bytes                                                                    
# |                                |                                                                              
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |           Key Salt             |  8 bytes                                                                     
# +--------------------------------+                                                                              
# |           HMAC Tag             |  Variable length, varies with                                                
# ...                            ...  digest algorithm                                                            
# |                                |                                                                              
# +---------------------------------                                                                              
# |        Encrypted Data          |                                                                              
# |                                |                                                                              
# |                                |  Variable length                                                             
# ...                            ...                                                                              
# |                                |                                                                              
# +---------------------------------
```

Should the HMAC Tag cover just the encrypted data and the IV (that is what it does currently)? Is it desirable/practical to provide some integrity for the other parts of the header as well?

Comment: You might want to checksum the header, but I can't think of any particular attack that could be made possible by modifying the header that an HMAC would protect from.

Comment: Also, note that this doesn't provide complete algorithmic agility. For example, you're stuck using block ciphers with a fixed block size and a specific mode of operation, and you're limited to using HMAC. What if you want to use ChaCha20-Poly1305? What if you wanted to use a block cipher with a 256-bit block size (so a 32 byte IV)?

Comment: @forest yeah, the format described is the current one. I'm considering what might be better. I'm considering combining cipher/hmac into a single field which represents a predefined set of cipher/hmac/whatever. The rest of the header would then vary based on the indicated cipher suite.

Answer (score 2):

The layout of the format doesn't matter much.  I would recommend combining all the parameters into a single cipher suite name so that you're not tempted to make nonsensical combinations: just use NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 (or AES-GCM if you must use AES, with the caveat that it subjects your users to side channel attacks on software AES implementations), not your own composition of AES256-CTR with HMAC-SHA256.

What matters much more is:

- **How many cryptographic decisions are imposed upon users who are not competent to answer questions on this site?**  Correct answer: *none*.

  For example, although the [scrypt file format](https://github.com/Tarsnap/scrypt/blob/master/FORMAT) has some options, there are no cipher fields—just a format version number.  There are cost parameters for the password-based key derivation function, but when creating files, even those are automatically calibrated by the [scrypt utility](https://tarsnap.com/scrypt) by default, with the option to specify them manually.
- **How are the parties in the system to behave when fed instances of the format?**  Be careful to specify *protocol*, not just *data*.  How do you use the key and act on the file?

  If you are using a key for a particular purpose, say an RSASSA-PSS public verification key, *do not let the format dictate another purpose*.  The implementation ecosystem of JavaScript Web Tokens, JWT, is a disaster because it was designed as a lofty view of data, abstracted from the reality of protocols.

  JWT implementations often expose a generic `verify(token, key)` function which *uses `key` however the attacker-controlled `token` prescribes*.  Even if you *meant* for `key` to be an RSASSA-PSS public verification key, `token` might say ‘hey, JavaScript chump, please use HMAC-SHA256!’, and you, the chump who used JWT, will happily use the ‘RSASSA-PSS public verification key’ in the place of an HMAC-SHA256 key which enables trivial forgery since RSASSA-PSS public verification keys are, well, often public.